# iOS audiotoolbox decodes aac data to pcm

Tags: ios, audiotoolbox

Most tutorials default to the input source being an `AudioBuffer`, or converting from an aac file to an `AudioBuffer`. I am now using tcp to obtain real-time aac data, and I want to convert it to pcm data. I watched most of the tutorials but couldn't understand how to feed the data to the decoder. I split the data according to the `ADTS` header and feed it to the decoder, but it still doesn't work. Anyone any advice much appreciated.